# Dll exporting a constructor risks causing heap corruption

Tags: c++, dll

I am working on a program with a plugin system which allows users to develop their own modules in the form of DLL files.
The modules are supposed to use objects which are defined in a DLL imported by all the components of the application. Here is what a sample object would look like:

```
#include <boost/system/api_config.hpp>

#if defined BOOST_WINDOWS_API
    #ifdef EXPORT
        #define API    __declspec(dllexport)
    #else
        #define API    __declspec(dllimport)
    #endif
#else
    #define API
#endif

class A
{
public:
    API A();
    API virtual ~A();
};
```

All DLLs are built statically (with their own CRT) and with the exact same compilation flags. I know that exchanging objects through DLL boundaries can get hairy, so I use `boost::shared_ptr`s almost everywhere. There is one difficulty around the object constructors though: if I create the object on the stack (from a different DLL), everything works as expected. But if I use the operator `new`, the heap gets corrupted whet the object is deleted.

```
A a; // Works fine, no problem when the object goes out of scope.

A* b = new A();
delete b; // Causes heap corruption!
```

What is the proper way around this? I feel that the code would be less readable if I had to define a method in the object's DLL such as `A* A::create() { return new A(); }`. In the worst scenario, I'm thinking of making the `new` operator private, to make sure that the user won't use it.

Comment: I'm not sure I get your problem.  From what you've shown, there's nothing in your DLL, since all of the functions are `inline`.  And you normally don't need a `__declspec` on an inline function or a template.

Comment: If I change the code so that the constructor and destructor aren't inline, it works for me.  Are you sure you're specifying compatible linker options for both the DLL and the code which uses it?  (In particular, you probably need `/MD` or `/MDd` systematically.  Without it, you will see that sort of problem.)

Comment: My constructor / destructor aren't actually inline, I edited the post to reflect that. I confirm that I get a heap corruption. My build flags are indeed `/MT` and `/MTD`, but I don't want to change those.

Comment: @executifs Are you `delete`ing the memory from the same DLL that you're `new`ing it in? (Is the issue reproducible if you immediately follow the `new` with the `delete`, as shown in your sample code?)

Comment: @Lilshieste Yes and yes: doing the delete immediately after the new (in the same source file) causes the crash.

Comment: @Lilshieste No need.  Once the destructor is `virtual` (and maybe even if it isn't), the actual call to the `operator delete` function will be in the destructor (and thus in the DLL where the destructor is located), _not_ in the delete expression.  And since `/MT` and `/MTd` result in DLLs which require `free` to be in the same DLL which executes `malloc`, he's screwed.

Comment: @JamesKanze Thanks, I didn't know that about virtual destructors. Definitely good info.

Comment: @Lilshieste It may be the case for all destructors, but it is almost a necessity for virtual destructors; in order to know which `operator delete` function to call, we have to be in the most derived class (which could have a class specific `operator delete`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your responsed to my comments: `/MT` and `/MTd` don't
work well with DLLs (even if they are the default).  If you want
to use DLLs and dynamic allocation, you *must* use `/MD` or
`/MDd`.  When you use `/MT` or `/MTd`, you effectively tell the
system to use a separate heap for each DLL.  Which means that
allocating in one, and deleting in another will corrupt the
heap.  And when the destructor is virtual, the actual `delete`
will be in the destructor, *not* in the `delete` expression.
(The actual issue is with `malloc` and `free`, called by the
`operator new()` and `operator delete()` functions.)

The classical way of working around this is to use factory
methods for dynamic allocation and a static or a member function
for delete.  An alternative (not tried, but I think it would
work) is to defined non-inline `operator new()` and `operator
delete()` members, which just forward to `malloc` and `free`.
(In the case of `operator new`, of course, you have to check
that the pointer you get from `malloc` isn't null, and throw an
`std::bad_alloc` if it is.)

But these are just work-arounds for a situation which shouldn't
exist.  Everything works fine with `/MD` or `/MDd`, and this is
what you should be using (even if it means you can't legally
deploy the debug version on machines which don't have a license
for Visual Studios).

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem could be related to the fact that you are mixing heaps. When you build your DLL with all CRT statically linked in it means that it maintains its own heap. However the commands `new` and `delete` from your host process are using the process heap. I think this configuratin can cause issues. I think the best way is to add two methods to your DLL: `CreateA()` and `DestroyA()`, and use only them for allocation/destruction of heap objects from DLL A.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to simply never export a constructor from a DLL. Export a factory function instead. Never export a concrete class while you're at it. Export pure abstract classes only. Which is a good style anyway, for reduced coupling and all associated goodies.